# "inline" directive doesn't work (Pure C)

Tags: c, inline

I have this:

```
inline void ololo(int a) {
    printf(a);
}

int main() {
    int b = 100;
    ololo(b);
}
```

When I try to build program with `gcc filename.c`, I get this error message:

```
/tmp/ccJovQFR.o: In function `main':
trololo.c:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `ololo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I can reproduce your problem, but there's others. Be sure to first clean up all the other warnings (set `-Wall`). That's not now you use `printf`.

Comment: Show us whole code, this one is invalid and will not compile.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak Well, it *does compile* with gcc by default, but it also emits some warnings (-Wimplicit-function-declaration and -Wint-conversion).

Comment: This is a c99 feature (`extern inline`). This documentation from clang has a good explanation on it. Other compilers should have something similar, too. http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline

Comment: @JonasWielicki: that's weird: printf should not accept int as an argument. As long as it is not some kind of extension...

Comment: @MichałWalenciak It’s an implicit cast from int to const char*, hence the -Wint-conversion warning.